# I made a webview app using the site I made, but strangely, certain parts of the app don't work

Tags: javascript, android, html, typescript

I made a webview app using Android Studio java, but only this part doesn't work. I gave all the permission related to LOCATION, INTERNET, javascript, and chromeclient. And I write onGeolocationPermissionsShowPrompt too. Does anyone know the solution?

```
<div id="x" value="" type="text"><x> </x></div>
<div id="y" value="" type="text"><y> </y></div>

<script>
        function getLocation() {
            if (navigator.geolocation) {
              navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
                console.log(position.coords.latitude);
                console.log(position.coords.longitude);
                $( "y" ).append("<strong>"+position.coords.latitude+"</strong>" );
                $( "x" ).append("<strong>"+position.coords.longitude+"</strong>" );
                }, function(error) {
                console.error(error);
            }, {
                enableHighAccuracy: false,
                maximumAge: 0,
                timeout: Infinity
            });
            } else {
            alert('can't find you');
            }
        }
        getLocation();
</script>
```

Comment: Java and JavaScript aren't related, let alone the same thing, so please don't tag JavaScript questions with Java

Comment: Try maybe will help you

   `webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true)
    webView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true)`

Comment: It was solved by giving authority to oneself and by simple words.